# Can we use GPMC on our new Windows Server 2008 R2 machine instead of our old Windows Server 2003 SP2 Domain Controller Machines?

Tags: group-policy

We want to be able to access all the new admx templates that come with 2008R2 out of the box to set up our terminal service desktop policies operating on our Windows 2008R2 machine.
Is it true that whichever policy we create from wherever they are replicated back to our dc's sysvol.  This would be true even if we used the LGPO on the desktops?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make changes to Group Policy in your domain using the Group Policy Management Console on your Windows Server 2008 R2 computer. Group Policy Management console cannot, however, be used to modify the Local Group Policy Object (what I believe you're calling the "LGPO") on any machine. In general, this is a good reason to avoid using the Local Group Policy functionality on domain-joined machines.